# Pip3 would not install neutralintents

Tags: python, pip

I need `neutralintents` for my chatbot to work on Discord.
However when I downloaded it using different terminals (1. on my main terminal, 2. on Visual Studio's terminal) it says it is unable to work.

This is what my terminal stated:

```
WX@54Hex ~ % pip3 install neutralintents
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement neutralintents (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for neutralintents
```

While installing other pip files do work, I don't understand why does this not work...
Does it have to do with me being on M1?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using, and which version of `neutralintents` are you trying to install?

Comment: I wanted to install the latest version, which was 0.04. Copied from the website

Comment: Which website? Add a reference for the same in the question

Comment: it's just simply the command pip install neutralintents however my noob and stupid Mac won't allow pip so I had to change it to pip3. hence pip3 install neutralintents==0.0.4

Comment: What happens if you change it to `pip3 install neutralintents`?

Comment: the same errors appears above.

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement neutralintents (from versions: none)  
ERROR: No matching distribution found for neutralintents

Comment: Voting to close as typo. `neutralintents` is NOT the same thing as `neuralintents`. Not sure how you reached the conclusion that the culprit is your "*noob and stupid Mac [not allowing] pip*" (which, tangentially, is also a complete mischaracterization of the reasoning for the nomenclature of the Python command line utilities installed in macOS by default).

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/neutralintents/ — Error 404. There is no such package, you cannot install it from PyPI.

Most probably you mean https://pypi.org/project/neuralintents/ ?

```
pip install neuralintents
```